# LXC container shows disk space of main node

Tags: linux, lxc

I have installed lxc on centos 6 and file based container and one lv based container however both show disk space of the main node and not the resources allocated to the containers after df -h

df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G  2.7G   16G  15% /
none             20G  2.7G   16G  15% /dev/shm

I have allocated 4 gb disk space to the contianer . Any solution ?

Comment: Perhaps if we could see how you did the space allocation, we could help.

Comment: Mounted an lv of 4gb in the containers CONTAINER_NAME/rootfs/etc/fstab

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I am also having the same issue now.

Comment: I compiled lxcfs for resource limit, it works.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to remove /etc/mtab and replace it with a symlink to /proc/mounts. This worked for me, but I'm not entirely certain that there aren't any side effects.